# MOSFET channel length

Tags: mosfet, frequency

Good day,
If you look on google for ARF446/447 in the datasheet you won't find the channel length (in micrometers). I need it to calculate the unity gain cutoff frequency. 
Also in the case of IRFP360 it's the same, it doesn't appear in the datasheet and other transistors as well. Is there a catalogue for this?
https://nptel.ac.in/courses/Webcourse-contents/IIT-Delhi/Semiconductor%20Devices/LMB2A/5h.htm

Comment: No producer will share with you the details of the geometry of its devices, unless the performance of their product relies not only on the geometry, but on other characteristics of their technological process. Otherwise it would just be like saying: "Copy my products".

Answer (score 1):

No, this is generally proprietary information and the manufacturers do not supply it. However, if you have a SPICE model for the transistor you may be able to glean the channel length from those parameters.